# Discord.py Command to add and ban words into a db

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So I'm wanting to be able to do a command that will add a word to a json file attached to the server id. I have the json file and it storing the server id and name and then loading what is in the json file but I can't seem to add any words to it using a command. Any ideas?

```
    async def open_bword(guild):

        guilds = await get_bword_data()

        if str(guild.id) in guilds:
            return False
        else:
            guilds[str(guild.id)] = {}
            guilds[str(guild.id)][str(guild)] = {}
            guilds[str(guild.id)]["Banned Words"] = 0

        with open('banwords.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(guilds,f)

        return True

    async def get_bword_data():
        with open('banwords.json','r') as f:
            guilds = json.load(f)

        return guilds

    async def update_bword(guild,change=0,mode = 'Banned Words'):
        guilds = await get_bword_data()

        guilds[str(guild.id)][mode] += change

        with open('banwords.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(guilds,f)
        list = guilds[str(guild.id)]['Banned Words']
        return list


    class Banwords(commands.Cog):

      def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
      
      @commands.Cog.listener()
      async def on_ready(self):
        print('Banwords cog working')

      @commands.command(aliases=['list'])
      async def banlist(self, ctx):
          await open_bword(ctx.guild)
          guild = ctx.guild

          guilds = await get_bword_data()

          bannedwords_list = guilds[str(guild.id)]["Banned Words"]

          em = discord.Embed(title=f'{guild}',color = RandomColor())
          em.add_field(name="banned words", value=bannedwords_list)
          await ctx.send(embed= em)
```

Comment: open file for reading, read all data to memory (and close it), update data in memory open file for writing, write all data from memory (and close it)

Comment: maybe use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"`.

Comment: @furas I changed a little bit and it now writes and reads the separate json file.
However if I add a word lets say test and then do the command again to ban another word lets say apples the output in the json file is "testapples" but I want them to be separate and in a list format ie "test, apples" I'll post the code below for you

Comment: won't let me post the code but you can dm me and I'll send it @furas